# Activescaffold Rails 3 (vhochstein) STI localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, activescaffold

Im trying to localize the labels for ActiveScaffold STI children. In development it works fine with just this:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      rule: "Regla"
      concrete_rule: "Regla puntual"
      weekly_rule: "Regla semanal"
      monthly_rule: "Regla mensual"
```

But in production it always takes the default locale set in application. I know this is an Activescaffold problem and I have solved it for another labels setting the translations inside the key `active_scaffold` but it's not working for STI. Any help with this ?

EDIT:

I found where activescaffold gets the i18n translation but I still don't know how to make it to take the correct translation in a production environment.

```
new_sti_link.label = child.to_s.camelize.constantize.model_name.human
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the only way to achieve what I want is to monkey patch ActiveScaffold to accept lambdas as parameters for the labels and to evaluate them when rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean cache in your browser.
Or change in your production.rb this line from "true" to "false"

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. The problem here is that ActiveScaffold generates the controllers on load, so in development environment they are loaded for each request, but it production the controllers are loaded only once since they are cached. I found the only way to achieve what I want is to monkey patch ActiveScaffold to accept lambdas as parameters for the labels and to evaluate them when rendering the view.

Comment: Seems, it's better way. Although you can try to disable caching in production.rb "config.action_controller.perform_caching = true".

But as result you get significant falling of performance, and it's bad.